# mongoid embeds_many associated collection remain empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid5

I have two models

```
class Supplier < User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image
 include Mongoid::Document
 embedded_in :supplier
end
```

When I save images in nested form it gets save embeded in supplier collection i.e

```
 s = Supplier.first
 s.images #some Image records
```

But the problem is image collection itself remains empty i.e

```
 Image.count # gives 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents of your `Image` model are stored inside the document of your `Supplier` model. So basically there is no collection with name `images` created in mongo. Check that in your mongo console. You only will be having a `suppliers` collection and no `images` collection.

If you want to access Images directly without accessing a particular you can do this

```
Supplier.all.pluck(:images)
#It will give you an array of all images
```

Or implement `has_many`

```
class Supplier < User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

Comment: is it default behaviour of mongoid? It doesn't make sense to me. I could have created an array field if I needed that. But I want to fetch Image record based on id. `Image.find` not `Supplier.first.images.find`.

Comment: What you are looking for is a `has_many` instead of `embedds_many`.

Comment: Yeah that's the last option available